# How to Internationalize rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm currently stuck on creating different paths to the same resource based on locale. My current structure is http://example.com/fr/ and http://example.com/en/

In my routes.rb I currently have:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en/ do
 resources :units
 resources :careers, :only => [:index,:create]
end

scope "(:locale)", :locale => /fr/ do
 resources :units, :path => :unites
 resources :careers, :only => [:index,:create], :path => :demploi
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little more why you need this, e.g. what you try to do differently for each of the languages if both point to the same resource? Are you trying to have different behavior depending on the locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) for that purpose. The gem simplify lot of the work with the i18n urls.